# Where are update queries performed in a mongo replica set?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

When doing an update with mongo, you have the option to specify a query to limit the fields being updated. What I'd like to know is, does mongo perform the query portion of the update against the slave and just the writes are done on the master, or is the query performed against the master since that's where the updated records will be written?

In case it changes anything, I'm using pymongo in my app to make the update.

Comment: On the primary only, the slaves replicate from the primary

Comment: Thanks Sammaye. If you put that into an answer I'll accept it.